# ListView OnClick With Filter Returns Wrong Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with my listview after filtering, the onclick returns the wrong activity because of the original position of items before filtering, I'll try to do my best with the 
example below:

```
ITEM 1 (pos 0) [opens Activity A]
ITEM 2 (pos 1) [opens Activity B]
ITEM 3 (pos 2) [opens Activity C]
ITEM 4 (pos 3) [opens Activity D]
```

When I filter to get ONLY ITEM 3 and 4 I get this

```
ITEM 3 [opens activity A and NOT C] because after filtering it takes pos 0 and not 2 
ITEM 4 [opens activity B and NOT D] because after filtering it takes pos 1 and not 3
```

Please help with my code below:

```
public class ListViewAdapterProduct extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<ClassProductList> classProductlist = null;
private ArrayList<ClassProductList> arraylist;

public ListViewAdapterProduct(Context context, List<ClassProductList> classProductlist) {
    mContext = context;
    this.classProductlist = classProductlist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ClassProductList>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(classProductlist);
}

public class ViewHolder {        
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    ImageView photo;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return classProductlist.size();
}

@Override
public ClassProductList getItem(int position) {
    return classProductlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_single_row, null);

        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textLarge);
        holder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textSmall);
        holder.photo= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageThumb);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.title.setText(classProductlist.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.description.setText(classProductlist.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.photo.setImageResource(classProductlist.get(position).getImage());


    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(position == 0) {
                Intent intent0 = new Intent(mContext, ProductProductprod1.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent0);
            }

            if(position == 1) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(mContext, ProductProductprod2.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }        
    });

    return view;
}

// Filter Class
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    classProductlist.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        classProductlist.addAll(arraylist);
    }
    else
    {
        for (ClassProductList Product : arraylist)
        {
            if (Product.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
            {
                classProductlist.add(Product);
            }
        }
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why not associate the `Activity` you want to open with the `Product`?  Then inside of your `getView` method you can do something along the lines of this...

```
final Class activityClass = classProductlist.get(position).getActivityClass()
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, activityClass);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }        
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I want to get specific activities from the listview item clicked:
ProductProductprod1,
ProductProductprod2,
ProductProductprodn....etc, that's why I used "if" statements